# unexpected output from while loop

Tags: javascript

It is a while loop practice. When i =10, desired outcome is 'Countdown 10' , and when i = 0, the desired outcome is 'Blast Off'; else, the desired outcome should equal i;

the code works fine, no error message but just when i === 10, the outcome does not show 'Countdown 10' but showing 10 instead...

is there anything missing? I cannot figure out the error...

Below is the code...

```js
var i = 10;
while (i >= 0) {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  if (i === 10) {
    para.textContent = "Countdown" + i;
  }

  if (i === 0) {
    para.textContent = "Blast Off!"
  } else {
    para.textContent = i
  }

  output.appendChild(para);
  i--
}
```

Comment: It is overwritten by the `else` block of the next `if (i === 0)`. You can remove the first `if` and add an `else if (i === 10)` to the last if block

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `else` overwrites whatever came before.

For the ten cycle its set to the Countdown 10 here:

```
  if (i === 10) {
    para.textContent = "Countdown" + i;
  }
```

But then here it fails `i === 0` so runs the `else` on it instead, overwriting your initial `Countdown 10` value.

```
  if (i === 0) {
    para.textContent = "Blast Off!"
  } else {
    para.textContent = i
  }
```

If you want to keep it all together, you can keep on using `else` to chain them all together like:

```
var i = 10;
while (i >= 0) {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  if (i === 10) {
    para.textContent = "Countdown" + i;
  } else if (i === 0) {
    para.textContent = "Blast Off!"
  } else {
    para.textContent = i
  }

  output.appendChild(para);
  i--
}
```

This probably highlights another issue, that you should follow standard formatting. Your originally posted snippet makes this hard to see. If you are using Microsoft Visual Code to write you can press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format the document. Most editors have a function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an `else-if` condition to prevent overwriting results by an other `else`:

```
var i = 10;
while (i >= 0) {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  if (i === 10) {
    para.textContent = "Countdown" + i;
  }
  else if (i === 0) {
    para.textContent = "Blast Off!"
  } else {
    para.textContent = i
  }

  output.appendChild(para);
  i--
}
```